# how to close a popup window when the focus is gone out from it

Tags: javascript, html, popup

**Requirement:** A popup will be opened up from parent window, and it should get closed when the focus from the window is lost. (This should happen even when another application window is opened or came into focus).

**Tried code:** 
`<body onBlur='javascript:window.close();'>`

**Issue:**
On click within the body of the popup makes the popup closed.

**Compatibility:** ie6 and above, firefox.

I got a **workaround** from ***http://pro-thoughts.blogspot.com/2006/10/incorrect-behavior-of-windowonblur.html***

```
var active_element;  
var bIsMSIE;

function initiateSelfClosing() {  
  if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {  
    active_element = document.activeElement;  
    document.onfocusout = closeWnd;  
    bIsMSIE = true;  
  }  
  else { window.onblur = closeWnd; }  
}

function closeWnd() {  
  if (window.opener != null) {  
    if (bIsMSIE && (active_element != document.activeElement)) {  
      active_element = document.activeElement;  
    }  
    else {  
      window.close();  
    }  
  }  
}  


<body onload="initiateSelfClosing()">  
</body>
```

But here also one problem is there, if there is a print button in the page, and if am clicking on print > then cancelling the print job, the popup is getting closed.

Can some one help me pls...

Answer (score 2):

Little corrections in sathishkumar's answer

1.we need to convert `win` to jquery object

2.Apply blur event on jqvariable and not on `window`

3.`this.close` is good enough in definition of `onblur` event

```
 var win = window.open("URL");
 var jqwin = $(win);
  $(jqwin).blur(function() {
    this.close();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use document for blur event

```
  var win = window.open("URL");
  $(window).blur(function() {
    win.close();
  });
```

Comment: i am not sure but document does not have onblur event.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot attach onblur event to BODY but
you Can attach a function on Onblur event of window.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function closeme()
    {  
        window.close();
    }
    window.onblur=closeme;
</script>
```

Since you have Edited your Question, You can get more help [here](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/151657-problem-onblur-window-close-ms-ie-6-a)

Comment: Thanks for the help.
But this is also showing the same issue as shown by my piece of code. The popup is closed on click within the page